# Angular production with remote access?

Tags: angular

I have built SPA project and get output as `dist` with all compiled files.

The main file is `index.html`

How to share this directory to get access outside by IP address? I mean when user comes to IP of machine it should back him index.html

Comment: You mean, like, a server ?

Comment: Yes, I mean this

Comment: Internet is full of tutorials to do that, and it's completely unrelated to Angular. Have made a google search before posting your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dist folder is just a static website host it on using apache or nginx: Your proper host (shared or VPS) Or just put it on one of this services AWS S3 / netlify / heroku ...

Comment: Can I share this under Windows Server?

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Yes sure check this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/creating-websites/scenario-build-a-static-website-on-iis